# $(this) acts like both event and <div>

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm a long-time procedural programmer now assigned to a web-app and studying jquery from a book.  The exercise is to run some code on one div selected from a row of 4 `<div>`s using `.each()`.  I attempted to store the div object that was clicked, then match it as the `.each` looped thru the 4 divs.

My following code works after trial and error, but the same `$(this)` seems to sometimes point to a div object, and sometimes to an event object.

1. How do you explain that behavior?
2. I understand that `.context` is deprecated.  I tried .target but that didn't seem to work.  Is there something else that I should be using?

My primary interest is to understand what is going on (question 1), so if you can provide an explanation and not just an alternative solution (question 2), I'd really appreciate it.  Thank you in advance.  Here are the code snippets:

```
<body>
    <div id="header">
        <h2>Jump for Joy Sale</h2>
    </div>
    <div id="main">
        <div class="guess_box"><img src="images/jump1.jpg"/></div>
        <div class="guess_box"><img src="images/jump2.jpg"/></div>
        <div class="guess_box"><img src="images/jump3.jpg"/></div>
        <div class="guess_box"><img src="images/jump4.jpg"/></div>
    </div>
    <script src="scripts/jquery-1.6.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/my_script.js"></script>
</body>
```

**Jscript**

```
$(document).ready(function() 
{
    $(".guess_box").click(checkForCode);

    function checkForCode() 
    {
        var code_box = 2;
        var discount_code = getRandomNum(1,100);
        var clicked = $(this);  // debugger says clicked is an event object
        var iteration = 0;

        $(".guess_box").each(function()
        {
            if ($(this).context === $(clicked).context) //act like event objs
            {  
                if (iteration === code_box) 
                {
                    // clicked on correct box
                    $(this).addClass("discount");  //same $(this) acts like <div>
                    discount_msg = "<p>Your Code: CODE"+ discount_code +"</p>";
                    return(false);
                }
            } 
            else 
            {
                if (iteration === code_box) 
                {
                    // if wrong box clicked, highlight the right one
                    $(this).addClass("no_discount");
                    discount_msg = "<p>Sorry, no discount this time</p>";
                    return(false);
                }
            }

            iteration += 1;
        });

        $(".guess_box").unbind();

        $(this).append(discount_msg);  // don't worry about this line
    } //checkForCode
}); //ready
```

Comment: In the explanation paragraph, "4 s" should be "4 divs", two places.  Formatter ate stuff between tag symbols.

Comment: "*debugger says clicked is an event object*" - care to elaborate?

Comment: @Amit - looks like this:
clicked [object(e)]
    _proto_ [object (e)]
    context [object HTMLDivElement]
   length 1
    [0] [object HTMLDivElement]

Comment: So the debugger doesn't say anything about an event object, right?

Comment: what debugger is that? looks like you just copied that from an `alert()`

Comment: @Pamblam  I hit F12 on the browser, selected Debugger.  I could not paste an image of what I saw, so I just copied the text.

Comment: @Amit   I assumed object (e) meant an event object

Comment: Prime example of why using 'this' can be tricky at times. I'd recommend reading up on Scoping in Javascript a bit to better understand what's happening here. Side note: You can utilize the 'event' parameter in your callback as noted in the documentation here https://api.jquery.com/click/  .This parameter will contain the 'event' object on which you can call .target to reference the DOM element   e.g. //function checkForCode(e)  --- 'e' being the event object

Answer (score 0):

The context of `this` depends on where and how it's used. if your function is called by an an event it will refer to the target of the event, otherwise it will refer to the object being called upon.

What youre seeing in your console is not `this`, or an event object, it's a jQuery object. If you want to inspect `this` you need to remove the jQuery wrapper function.

```
console.log(this);
```

[Event example..](https://jsfiddle.net/50k5xhbo/)

```
<div>click me</div>

$("div").click(function(){
    // referring to the div itself
    $(this).text("you clicked me");
    // Note you can do it without jQuery as well
    // this.innerHTML = "you clicked me";
});
```

[object example](https://jsfiddle.net/sgpLa9ky/)

```
function something(){
    this.something = "something";
    this.doAThing = function(){
        this.something = "something new";
    }
}

var thing = new something();
thing.doAThing();
alert(thing.something);
```

Comment: Thank you Pamblam, I will try that.  I am trying to understand why I can use both .context and .addClass on the same $(this), unless .context also applies to div objects (or vice versa).

Comment: @Marlin my advice to you is to read a few basic Javascript tutorials before jumping into (relatively) advanced jQuery. the `$` is simply a Javascript function with an unusual name. It's just like any other function. Whatever you put between the perens is just a parameter to the jQuery function. That said, every jQuery object you create is going to have the same properties and methods. For that reason they will also all look similar in the console. `context` and `addClass()` are just jquery props/methods. they exist and can be used on any jQuery object.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to those that responded.  As Pamblam indicated, I was confusing this and $(this).  I replaced 2 lines in my code and it makes more sense:

`clicked = $(this)`  becomes  `clicked = this`

`if ($(this).context === $(clicked).context)`  becomes 
`if (this === clicked)`